# Как это можно оптимизировать?

Tags: c#

Как это можно оптимизировать и привести в нормальный вид?

```
public void NewGenerating()
{
    Generating = Random.Range(1, 5);
    if (Generating == 1)
    {

    }
    if (Generating == 2)
    {

    }
    if (Generating == 3)
    {

    }
    if (Generating == 4)
    {

    }
    if (Generating == 5)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: `switch` *(7 символов нужно...)*

Comment: а что не так с нормальностью сейчас?

Answer (score 5):

Обычное ветвление с использованием условного оператора не является чем-то зазорным.
Пока ветки не содержат вложенных инструкций, блок кода может выглядеть излишне раздутым, но это перестанет быть таковым, когда в условиях будет реализация.

C# также позволяет осуществлять ветвление с помощью оператора `switch`. Однако следует понимать, что выражения во всех `case` должны быть одного и того же типа.

```
public void NewGenerating()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    switch (r.Next(1, 5))
    {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
    }
}
```

Также можно использовать словарь значений `Dictionary(int, Action)`. В качестве ключа - сгенерированное число, в качестве значения - функция с инструкциями, которая позже вызывается.

```
public void NewGenerating()
{
    Dictionary<int, Action> vars = new Dictionary<int, Action>();

    vars.Add(1, () => { /*Console.WriteLine("1 was generated");*/ });
    vars.Add(2, () => { });
    vars.Add(3, () => { });
    vars.Add(4, () => { });
    vars.Add(5, () => { });

    Random r = new Random();

    Action ac = vars[r.Next(1, 5)];
    ac();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь :)